# LLVM runs into a linker error after upgrade

Tags: macos, haskell, llvm, ld, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell `stack` project where I have been using the `llvm-hs` library for building a compiler which emits LLVM IR. I had been working with LLVM version 8.0.0 so far. Recently due to a Python upgrade in my system the LLVM version got bumped to 8.0.1.

When I attempt to do `stack build` I get the following error -

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm-8/8.0.0/lib/llvm-8/lib'
ld: library not found for -lLLVM-8
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

It seems from the above that ld is looking for `-L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm-8/8.0.0/lib/llvm-8/lib` whereas on my system I currently have the version for 8.0.1. How do I point `ld` to the correct path?

I am running MacOS Mojave. stack version 2.3.1. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was capable of solving this by adding the following to my `.bash_profile`

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/llvm-8/8.0.1/lib/llvm-8/lib"
```

Hope this helps if someone ran into the same problem.